# Anyone seen software to use your mobile (WinMo / Android) as a separate screen for your laptop?

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors, mobile-phone

This is a USB monitor for a laptop:

http://www.lilliputweb.net/index.php?Controller=User_Product&action=ShowProduct&product_id=83

I was wondering if anyone has seen some software that would run your mobile as a separate screen through a USB connection?

Answer (score 1):

This monitor seems to be more or less an implementation of [Windows SideShow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_SideShow), no ? If so, there is an [implementation](http://www.threemote.com/) for [Android phones](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowssideshow/thread/b23e6900-8a84-498a-8fab-0f713ae74409) (which also works for Windows mobile). I didn't found anything for iOs, unfortunatly.

If it's not what you're searching, things will be a little more complex.

There seems to be something for iPad, similar to Maxivista : [Maxivista for iPad](http://www.maxivista.com/ipad_monitor.htm), but obviously nothing for iPhone (talk about segmentation !).

A long time ago, there was [Sidewindow](http://www.engadget.com/2005/07/18/sidewindow-turns-your-pocket-pc-into-a-secondary-display/) for Pocket PC (but all that is definitely dead).

Answer (score 1):

Yes sure! There is a popular app for iOS called iDisplay, and now it is available for Android as well :)

Here: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.idisplay.virtualscreen